# How do I use a PlayStation 3 Sixaxis controller with Ubuntu to control games

Tags: games, ps3

How do I use a PlayStation 3 controller with Ubuntu?

Comment: Answer for [Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/913600/139248) which really works!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use sixad/QtSixA http://qtsixa.sourceforge.net/ . Just install from the repo and pair with sixpair while the sixaxis is connected with usb, and then connect with Bluetooth by pressing the PS button.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:falk-t-j/qtsixa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qtsixa
```

Connect with USB

```
sixpair
```

Disconnect sixaxis from USB

```
sixad -s
```

press PS button to connect over bluetooth

Comment: I Could not get this working on linux mint 17

Comment: Never mind I have just got this working!

Comment: Sorry for yet another comment but this is amazing with MAME!

Comment: This solution doesn't work anymore! Terminal says E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/falk-t-j/qtsixa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Answer (score 14):

You are able to connect the controller to the pc via usb cable. This is supplied with a PS3 device (it is the primary way to charge the controller). I don't know how to connect the controller via bluetooth to your computer (if you even have a bluetooth receiver), so this answer focusses on usb connection. It might be that the controller already works if you do this (You can test this with jstest-gtk as listed below). I use another similar PnP controller, and it works without difficulty.

if it does not work automatically, [this link](http://danielj.se/2013/04/26/how-to-get-your-playstation-3-dualshock-3-sixaxis-controller-to-work-on-linux/) might answer your question. In summary:

- install xboxdrv from the Ubuntu Software Center or with `sudo apt-get install xboxdrv`
- start xboxdrv with `sudo xboxdrv --detach-kernel-driver`
- If you press the Playstation button, the computer will receive its input and simulate it as an Xbox 360 controller, which should work the same as the playstation controller.

You can test the functionality of your controller through Jstest-gtk (install: `sudo apt-get install jstest-gtk`)

Good luck, let me know if it works.

Comment: I will try and let you know

Comment: Seems to work for me!

Comment: Doesn't work anymore with ubuntu 14.10. I tested it with the 14.04 debs.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Works on Pop_Os like a charm

Answer (score 11):

**There is nothing to install** anymore on recent versions of Ubuntu, as Dualshock 3 (and 4 I believe) is **natively supported** by the Kernel, in **both USB and Bluetooth**.

## USB Usage

If you want to use it also via Bluetooth, prefer to make the Bluetooth setup first.

Connecting the controller via USB *just works*™ out of the box. The main drawback is that the controller remains paired with your PlayStation, so when you disconnect the controller, it turns on the PlayStation. Remember to turn it off.

To avoid this, you need to pair the controller via Bluetooth, which will un-pair it from the console.

## Bluetooth usage

### First connection

1. If you controller is connected over USB, disconnect it first.
2. Open Bluetooth settings in the Gnome Control Center
3. Ensure Bluetooth is enabled, and keep that window open
4. Connect the controller via USB
5. Accept the confirmation dialog that opens:
   [image: Confirm Bluetooth Connection dialog]
6. Disconnect the USB cable

Note that this will dissociate the controller from your PlayStation (otherwise it would still turn it on when you press the PlayStation button). If you want to re-associate it, you will need to connect it via cable first, like you did with your PC.

### Following connections

From now on, you just have to press the PlayStation button to connect it via Bluetooth to your PC.

### Turning off the controller

There are 2 options to turn off the controller:

1. Hold the PlayStation button for 10 seconds; or
2. Go to the Bluetooth settings, select your device, and disconnect it with the toggle.

Comment: Nowadays it happens like this, but after the step 6, at the first connection it asks the pin! It proposes already a PIN, the default it's not valid neither 0000 or 000000!

Comment: @Cirelli94 I doubt I could help you, I haven’t seen that with the Dualshock 3 controllers I have. What type of controllers are yours?

Comment: Sony PlayStation Dualshock 3 !
This behaviour has changed recently, so maybe something changed with linux or it's my controller fault and it's going to die :)

Answer (score 10):

Sorry to be that guy but [compiling from source](https://retropie.org.uk/forum/topic/2913/guide-use-qtsixa-on-ubuntu-16-04-and-derivatives/) worked for me and the PPA has been pretty quiet for a while now (not weird at all considering the GitHub hasn't been updated in 4 years and the "final" version was released around the same time), so don't hold your breath for a xenial package.

The excellent guide I linked gives you a few commands to download all prereqs and compile but I will summarize here:

```
sudo apt-get update &&
  sudo apt-get install git dialog build-essential pyqt4-dev-tools libusb-dev libjack-dev libbluetooth-dev python-dbus checkinstall -y &&
  git clone https://github.com/falkTX/qtsixa.git && 
  cd qtsixa &&
  make &&
  sudo checkinstall
```

Comment: I get nathan@nathan-vm:~/projects/sixad-master$ sudo sixpair
USB_REQ_GET_CONFIGURATION: Broken pipe
Current Bluetooth master: Unable to retrieve local bd_addr from `hcitool dev`.
Please enable Bluetooth or specify an address manually.

Answer (score 1):

For those still looking for the answer in Ubuntu 22.04, I've found the work-around.  See my post on Stack Overflow or the original bug report:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77769154/5022999
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/2045931

- Edit `/etc/bluetooth/input.conf`

- Uncomment `ClassicBondedOnly=true` and change to `ClassicBondedOnly=false`
- Restart bluetooth: `systemctl restart bluetooth`

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 15.10/16.04 and Linux Mint 18, you can still use the QtSixA PPA, but specifying "vivid" as the Ubuntu version (15.04), since that was the last officially supported version. To do so, execute the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/falk-t-j/qtsixa/ubuntu vivid main"
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 736E4F0B
sudo apt update
sudo apt install sixad
```

Note: as far as I can tell, the GUI based application is no longer useful, at least to detect and connect controllers through Bluetooth. Because of that, you need to use the command line-based applications, i.e. `sixad` and `sixpair`

Edit: Apparently and according to my tests, sixad automatically starts at the boot, but doesn't work at all when that happens, having to stop it an re-start it to make it to work. To prevent sixad from being started at the boot, you have to execute:

```
sudo systemctl disable sixad
```

and, when you're going to use it, execute:

```
sudo sixad -s
```

of course, all the above is because QTSixA is no longer supported. The PS3 and PS4 controllers are supposed to work natively in Linux, but I still prefer to use it instead of the native support. I haven't been able to connect my PS3 controllers natively, and when I use QTSixA, I can do other things like specify the Bluetooth MAC address to be paired with.

I think I will mail the developer to know if it's possible for him to resume the support. I believe that only applying small modifications, the project could work properly out-of-the-box. And, even without doing anything, the PPA could still work.

Comment: Not work for me on 16.04

Comment: Pair is sucessful but don't connect to controller.

Comment: @Maxwel Leite are you able to start sixad successfully? Did you take into account what I explained about preventing sixad from starting at the boot?

Comment: yes sixad starts and wait for press PS button - does work and yes, I disable sixad from start on boot .Thank you for try to help me but [I solve the problem for my own](https://askubuntu.com/a/913600/139248).

Answer (score -2):

PPA won't work on Ubuntu Xenial derivates but there is a solution. If you have Ubuntu 16.04 and would like to use `qtsixa`, you can use these commands to trick the PPA into thinking that you’re running 15.10:

```
sudo cp /etc/lsb-release /etc/lsb-release.backup
sudo gedit /etc/lsb-release
```

Change the following lines to the values below:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu

DISTRIB_RELEASE=15.10

DISTRIB_CODENAME=wily

DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Trusty Tahr"
```

and save.

Now install the PPA for `qtsixa`. Then copy the original `lsb-release` file back to were it was.

```
sudo cp /etc/lsb-release.backup /etc/lsb-release
```

Now you can reboot.

```
sudo reboot
```

Useful for using Intel Graphics Installer for Linux™ too, tested in Linux Mint 18 thanks to [this post](https://allanbogh.com/2016/01/05/ubuntu-16-04-installing-the-intel-graphics-drivers-using-the-intel-graphics-installer-for-linux/).

Comment: This not recommended... this cold break your system

Comment: Answer downvoted. Changing the description of your release is NOT the way you do things on Ubuntu or Debian.

Comment: Changing `lsb-release` files is a very bad idea and can lead to extreme breakage. While this may get the PS3 controller working, the draw backs of this approach outweigh any benefits.