# Is it possible to connect both a bluetooth headset and a ps3 controller via bluetooth wirelessly?

Tags: drivers, sound, bluetooth

I recently installed [qtsixa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409761/how-do-i-use-a-ps3-sixaxis-controller-with-ubuntu-to-control-games) to connect my ps3 controller via Bluetooth. Now the problem is that, after installing it, the bluetooth tray icon dissappeared even when my controller is disconnected. When I was on windows, I couldn't use both my controller and headset simultaneously, but maybe I could on here?

So really, I have 2 problems:

- My bt tray icon doesn't show up
- I want to know if I can connect my controller and headset simultaneously

I am running Ubuntu 19.10 on the KDE Plasma Desktop Env.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, something happened and I can just connect my controller AND headset using the standard ubuntu bluetooth driver. I am afraid to uninstall qtsixa eventhough it supposedly isn't on.

Answer (score 0):

I figured half of it out. [This](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1449080) bug submission matches my problem and the solution (detailed at [comment #7](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1449080/comments/7)) worked for me, too. 
Long story short, qtsixa removes the execute attribute of /usr/sbin/bluetoothd (the bluetooth service), so it cannot run anymore.
I fixed it by stopping qtsixa with

```
sixad --stop
```

After wich I modified the attributes of the service like this

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/sbin/bluetoothd
```

And then started the service

```
sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service
```

Running the `sixad --start` command however reverts all of the above. I have yet to integrate all this into a startup command.